# Is Android concurrency parallelism or concurrency?

Tags: android, concurrency

Are Android applications using real parallelism? Or it just concurrency? as I read it using Preemptive multitasking, Preemptive is not real parallelism its just switching tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Both.  Android is built on Linux, and typically run on multicore processors.  So different threads can be scheduled on the same core, or on multiple cores.  Each core will be scheduled by Linux and use preemptive multitasking.  Pretty much the same as any other OS since the death of Mac OS 9.